# Filter by two date fields in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to apply a filter for two date fields on the same view.
I created a **Last N months** parameter and a calculated field to view the desired period.

`creation_date` is used to find customer acquisition.
`closure_date` is used to find churn.

Normally I use the following field to filter by creation_date:

```
DATEDIFF('month', [creation_date], TODAY()) > 0 
AND DATEDIFF('month', [creation_date], TODAY()) <= [Last N months]
```

What I want is also to include another date field, `closure_date` in the filter, like this:

```
(DATEDIFF('month', [creation_date], TODAY()) > 0 AND DATEDIFF('month', [creation_date], TODAY()) <= [Last N months])
OR
(DATEDIFF('month', [closure_date], TODAY()) > 0 AND DATEDIFF('month', [closure_date], TODAY()) <= [Last N months])
```

When using this field in Filters and selecting `TRUE`, it shows the same correct number of Customer Acquisition, but Churn is different wrongly.

How can I write the statement to filter by two dates properly?

Comment: can you please explain a bit more by posting sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have something like this

```
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| Customer_Id | date_of acq | date_of_churn |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| A           | 02-11-2020  | 28-11-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| B           | 05-07-2020  | 08-07-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| C           | 11-11-2020  | 30-11-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| D           | 24-11-2020  | 03-01-2021    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| E           | 09-08-2020  | 15-08-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| F           | 04-07-2020  | 12-07-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| G           | 16-06-2020  | 25-07-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| H           | 14-12-2020  | 01-01-2021    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| I           | 12-07-2020  | 13-08-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| J           | 28-11-2020  | 30-12-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| K           | 04-09-2020  | 24-09-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| L           | 20-09-2020  | 12-10-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| M           | 12-12-2020  | 21-12-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| N           | 26-10-2020  | 03-12-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| O           | 27-06-2020  | 28-07-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| P           | 25-07-2020  | 30-08-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| Q           | 14-12-2020  | 11-01-2021    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| R           | 09-09-2020  | 01-10-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| S           | 23-06-2020  | 16-07-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| T           | 05-09-2020  | 03-10-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| U           | 16-09-2020  | 28-09-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| V           | 30-11-2020  | 25-12-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| W           | 24-08-2020  | 19-09-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| X           | 21-08-2020  | 08-09-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| Y           | 20-06-2020  | 09-07-2020    |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

If I am correct, then you have to first pivot the two date columns in Tableau so that you get something like this..

[image]

Now If you'll modify your filter on the date column you'll be able to filter out either `acquisition` or `churn` or `both`.  Something like this..(this is for last 2 months)

[image]

further check the results

[image]